# PHP Follow system query error

Tags: php, pdo, social-networking

I'm currently implementing a follow system similar to twitter. The issue is one of the queries will not seem to work.

I have two databases; tbl_users and follow.

tbl_users contains: userId, userName, userEmail, userPass, and followers_count

follow contains: follow_id, receiver, sender, and status

In class USER I have the following function:

```
 //get all users from database where userID not = your id
 public function users($user_id){
 global $pdo;
 $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tbl_users` U LEFT JOIN `follow` F on 
 `f`.`receiver` = `U`.`userID` AND CASE WHEN `F`.`sender` = ? THEN 
 `F`.`receiver` = `U`.`userID` END where `U`.`userID` != ?");
 $query->bindValue(1,$user_id);
 $query->bindValue(2,$user_id);
 $query->execute();
 return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }
```

In my index.php I call the following code:

```
$user_home = new USER();
$user_id = $_SESSION['userID'];
$users = $user_home->users($user_id);
```

Which returns this error:

```
 [29-Aug-2017 05:17:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a
 member function prepare() on null in
 /home/iamlive/public_html/class.channel.php:143 
Stack trace:
 #0 /home/iamlive/public_html/index.php(25): USER->users('1')
 #1 {main} thrown in /home/iamlive/public_html/class.channel.php on line 143
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid statement? That use of `CASE` looks suspicious.

Comment: Well it might be a suspicious case, but the error tells us that the connection to the database doesn't yet exist, `$pdo` is NULL.

Comment: Don't use `global $pdo`. Given your function is a class method, save a reference to `$pdo` in your class, preferably injected via the constructor, eg `public function __construct(PDO $pdo) { $this->pdo = $pdo; }`